# Goutte / GuzzleHTTP Get the Content-Length / Size of the response body

Tags: php, guzzle, content-length, goutte

I am using https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte to scrape a page. No probs there.

I am trying to get the `Content-Length` from the client response object, but cannot see how I can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking through the docs... Use `$response = $client->getInternalResponse()` to get a `Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Response` which as a `$response->getHeader('Content-Length')` available. :-)